# How to combine two disks (partition and disk) if the partition holds the Ubuntu operating system?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, diskmanagement

I have a new server that came with two 1 TB SSD NVMe.

My goal is to create **one drive** with 2 TB. So I need to combine the two 1 TB.

I installed Ubuntu on SSD 1 with:

```
PART /boot/efi esp 256M
PART swap swap 31G
PART /boot ext3 1024M
PART / ext4 all
```

After the installation I see with `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
    nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
    ├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   256M  0 part /boot/efi
    ├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    31G  0 part [SWAP]
    ├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0     1G  0 part /boot
    └─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 921.6G  0 part /
    nvme1n1     259:5    0 953.9G  0 disk
```

Now my goal is to **combine** `part 921.6G nvme0n1p4` with `disk 953.9G nvme1n1` but I was not able to.

I read about [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) and a [LVM user guide](https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm), still, I could not figure out the right steps.

> The first step in creating an LVM is to take existing physical devices and convert them into physical volumes (PVs) ([Source](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/pvcreate-command-examples-in-linux/))

```
pvcreate /dev/nvme1n1                           # create physical volume from disk

vgcreate serverssd /dev/nvme0n1p4               # create volume group named "serverssd" and add partition to it
```

At this point I get the **error message:**

> Can't open /dev/nvme0n1p4 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
>
> Can't open /dev/nvme0n1p4 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?

I assume the issue is that Ubuntu is installed on `nvme0n1p4`. However, I was reading that this should not influence any disk management operations.

I assume from the tutorials the next step would be:

```
vgextend serverssd /dev/nvme1n1             # extend the existing Volume Group
```

Any help how to overcome the error message and get the task done is appreciated.

Comment: If the new server is still unused just reinstall the OS and utilize both disks. It's way easier than shuffling around existing partitions

Comment: I am using Hetzner that provides an [installimage](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/operating-systems/installimage/) script. How to tell to merge both disks at install time? Or just before installing Ubuntu? – Is `gparted` the way to go? – I also consider now assigning 100 GB for Ubuntu OS, so I have the other 900 GB free for later us with the 1 TB.

Comment: In the Hetzner docs for installimage it is written: "The installimage also supports adjustments to the partitioning scheme (including the use of LVM). You can find the designated syntax in the examples in the editor." – I have to take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create VG on second disk
2. copy files from original `/`
3. Change grub to boot from new disk
4. Add old disk to VG

(this is very high level workflow and for sure need extend/corrections)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the Ubuntu installation script (from the Rescue system), so it only uses 80G instead of all space of the disk for the Ubuntu drive.

Instead:

```
PART /boot/efi esp 256M
PART swap swap 31G
PART /boot ext3 1024M
PART / ext4 all
```

I used:

```
PART /boot/efi esp 256M
PART swap swap 31G
PART /boot ext3 1024M
PART / ext4 80G
```

After the installation I created a partition out of left space of `nvme0n1` and merged it with the partition of `nvme1n1`.

1. Create partition out of left space of nvme0n1:

   `parted /dev/nvme0n1`

   `print`

   Gives:

   ```
    Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
    1      2097kB  271MB   268MB   fat16                 boot, esp
    2      271MB   33.6GB  33.3GB  linux-swap(v1)        swap
    3      33.6GB  34.6GB  1074MB  ext3
    4      34.6GB  121GB   85.9GB  ext4
   ```

   Then:

   `mkpart primary ext4 121GB 100%`
   `quit`

   Then:

   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p5`
2. Create partition out of space of nvme1n1

   `parted /dev/nvme1n1`

   `mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%`
3. Use `lsblk` which gives:

   ```
    NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
    nvme1n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
    └─nvme1n1p1 259:8    0 953.9G  0 part 
    nvme0n1     259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk
    ├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   256M  0 part /boot/efi
    ├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0    31G  0 part [SWAP]
    ├─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0     1G  0 part /boot
    ├─nvme0n1p4 259:5    0    80G  0 part /
    └─nvme0n1p5 259:6    0 841.6G  0 part
   ```
4. We merge both partitions `nvme1n1p1` and `nvme0n1p5` into one VLM:

   - `pvdisplay` should return nothing
   - Create a Volume Group (VG):
     Combine the physical volumes into a volume group:
     `vgcreate my_volume_group /dev/nvme0n1p5 /dev/nvme1n1p1`
   - Create a Logical Volume (LV):
     Create a logical volume within the volume group:
     `lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n my_logical_volume my_volume_group`
   - Create a Filesystem:
     Create a filesystem on the logical volume. Replace ext4 with your preferred filesystem type:
     `mkfs.ext4 /dev/my_volume_group/my_logical_volume`
   - Mount the Logical Volume:
     Create a mount point and mount the logical volume:
     `mkdir /mnt/myserver`
     `mount /dev/my_volume_group/my_logical_volume /mnt/myserver`
   - Automount at Boot:
     If you want the logical volume to be mounted automatically at boot, add an entry to the `/etc/fstab` file:
     `echo "/dev/my_volume_group/my_logical_volume /mnt/myserver ext4 defaults 0 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab`
   - `lsblk` gives now:

```
NAME                                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme1n1                                 259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1                             259:8    0 953.9G  0 part
└─my_volume_group-my_logical_volume 253:0    0   1.8T  0 lvm  /mnt/myserver
nvme0n1                                 259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                             259:2    0   256M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                             259:3    0    31G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3                             259:4    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p4                             259:5    0    80G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p5                             259:6    0 841.6G  0 part
└─my_volume_group-my_logical_volume 253:0    0   1.8T  0 lvm  /mnt/myserver
```

- `lvdisplay` gives now:

```
LV Path                /dev/my_volume_group/my_logical_volume
LV Name                my_logical_volume
VG Name                my_volume_group
LV Size                1.75 TiB
```

- `reboot` and check if all LV are there